# How to install a Powershell module concurrently?

Tags: powershell, concurrency, module

I have a Pull Request validation build running for different branches, i.e. several concurrent instances of the build is a very common thing.

One of the things the build does is install a module. Now I could modify the profile on the build agent and install module from there, but I want to avoid any extra build agent configuration. So, my build installs a module in the current user scope.

I noticed that `Install-Module` does not seem to be safe when invoked concurrently - it may fail with all kinds of different and weird error messages.

Now I solved this with a named mutex acquired before and released after, but this causes abysmal performance - the code sometimes waits for 30 seconds and more.
So, how to solve this problem? How to install a powershell module concurrently, but safely and with good performance?

**EDIT 1**

It is frustrating. I am trying to trace the concurrent installs using `Set-PSDebug -Trace 2`, but apparently `Install-Module` has a lot of `Write-Debug` invocations calling to functions which are themselves not safe for concurrent execution! So trying to trace actually worsens matters.

Comment: Best option would be to use Runspaces and run the installation independently. Because the parameters are mostly same and there wont be any scope issue.

Comment: I do not understand. Could you elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `Install-Module` is totally **NOT SAFE** to run during a build where multiple builds run on the same agent. Looks like using a named Mutex is the safest approach.

**EDIT 1**

In a multi-threading environments invoking the following commands is not safe without explicit mutex:

- `Install-Module`
- `Import-Module`
- `Get-PSRepository` without arguments

Maybe more. In my code I invoke all the three commands, and I discovered that all of them together must be in the same mutex, i.e. these combinations do not work:

**Not working #1**

```
$mtx.WaitOne()
try
{
    Install-Module ...
}
finally
{
    $mtx.ReleaseMutex()
}
Import-Module ...
Get-PSRepository ...
```

**Not working #2**

```
$mtx.WaitOne()
try
{
    Install-Module ...
    Import-Module ...
}
finally
{
    $mtx.ReleaseMutex()
}
Get-PSRepository
```

The only safe option appears to be this one:

```
$mtx.WaitOne()
try
{
    Install-Module ...
    Import-Module ...
    Get-PSRepository
}
finally
{
    $mtx.ReleaseMutex()
}
```

Which is surprising, because I do not expect `Install-Module` or `Import-Module` to affect `Get-PSRepository`, yet somehow they do:

```
   ParameterBindingException: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Provider'.
   at Get-PSRepository<Process>, C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1: line 4496
   at Use-ModuleFB22C60E, C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\m_deadbeef_.ps1: line 167
   at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 4
```

Comment: Say you have 3 of these running concurrently, #2 and #3 will wait on the mutex to be available to import.  If you are importing different module versions at user scope, does #1 still use the different version of the module if you import #2?

Comment: I do not know. If you do not specify version explicitly, then you do not care. If you do specify it explicitly, then you get what you have requested.